# How to close an image opened by Photoimage (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have opened an image using the PhotoImage

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(bg=controller.backcolor, borderwidth=10) 

        def second_check():

            if(RadioVariety_1.get() == 0):

                image_path = "photo.jpg"
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image_path))
                panel = tk.Label(self, image = img, background=controller.backcolor)
                panel.image = img
                panel.place(x=600,y=50)

                def close_image():#############
                    img.destroy()        #not working

                close_radio=tk.Radiobutton(self, text="close the image", command=close_image)
                close_radio.place(x=1200,y=400)
```

I have tried like `img.destroy()`. But it isn't working.
`AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'destroy'`   
I want to close the image when the radio button is clicked.
What should I do?

Comment: replace `img.destroy()` with either `panel.destroy() ` or `panel.configure(image=None)`. Both should work depending on what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The part where you are making mistake is in the `close_image()` function definition. You are actually trying to destroy the photoimage object which is impossible rather than destroying the image object. PhotoImage obj doesnt have a destroy method. Moreover you have created your image using `tk.label`, so you have to try destroying that label to delete the image.

The solution is to use `panel.destroy()`. It will be destroying the label object. Note that, the Tkinter destroy method has the ability to “destroy” any Tkinter GUI objects.

So your revised code will be like this:

```py
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(bg=controller.backcolor, borderwidth=10) 

        def second_check():

            if(RadioVariety_1.get() == 0):

                image_path = "photo.jpg"
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image_path))
                panel = tk.Label(self, image = img, background=controller.backcolor)
                panel.image = img
                panel.place(x=600,y=50)

                def close_image():#############
                    panel.destroy()        #working

                close_radio=tk.Radiobutton(self, text="close the image", command=close_image)
                close_radio.place(x=1200,y=400)
```